# Как установить прелоадер на определенное время?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как установить прелоадер на определенное время. Например на 20 секунд? Чтобы он пропадал через 20 секунд, не дожидаясь полной загрузки страницы.

Код:

```
<div class="loader">
   <div class="loader_inner"></div>
</div>

<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
     $(".loader").fadeOut();
     $(".loader_inner").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
   });
</script>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643040/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-30-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BA%D1%83/643056#643056

Answer (score 2):

В вашем коде ошибка такого вида.

Как я понял, вы хотите установить таймаут с помощью  `.delay(400)`. Но перед этим вы вызываете  `$(".loader").fadeOut();` Но `.loader_inner` находится *внутри* `.loader` и при скрытии внешнего элемента, внутренние элементы тоже будут скрыты.

В зависимости от задачи, вам нужно либо скрыть общий элемент после таймаута:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
     $(".loader").delay(20000).fadeOut();
   });
</script>
```

Либо не скрывать его вовсе:

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function() {
     $(".loader_inner").delay(20000).fadeOut("slow");
   });
</script>
```

Так-же следует заметить, что 20 секунд - это 20000 миллисекунд.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне необходимо установить прелоадер на определенное время, чтобы он пропадал через 20 секунд например и не дожидался полной загрузки страницы.

Comment: Разница в вариантах только в том, какой элемент нужно скрыть